# How to read multiple element(Columns) in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have multiple element and attribute. i only want to read only few columns. from the code below, i only want to read Value and comment. excluding type,mimetype and space.

```
   <xsd:element name="data">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
            <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
          </xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
          <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
          <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
          <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
```

Here is the  code that i have used to read the file but it is showing with type,mimetype and space of which i don't want these extra columns. how do i do it

C# code

```
   #region this is the method that load the file to the grid
    public void load()
    {
        try
        {
            oDataSet = new DataSet();
            oDataTable = new DataTable();

            //there must always be a file selected
            if (txtInputfile.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                PathSelection = txtInputfile.Text;
            }
            //now adding the rows
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn C in Gridview_Input.Columns)
            {
                oDataTable.Columns.Add(C.DataPropertyName, C.ValueType);
            }

            foreach (DataGridView _Row in Gridview_Input.Rows)
            {
                DataRow row1 = oDataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < Gridview_Input.ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    oDataTable.Rows.Add(row1);
                }
            }
            //here am transfering the datatable to the dataset
            oDataSet.Tables.Add(oDataTable);
        }
```

Button which browse the file to load

```
  private void btnBrowse1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BrowseFile();
            //this method loads the file
            load();

            oDataSet = new DataSet();
            //now am reading the files fro the path that is selected
            oDataSet.ReadXml(PathSelection);
            Gridview_Input.DataSource = oDataSet;
            Gridview_Input.DataMember = "Data";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured.\nError message: " + ex.Message, "Error Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object with the variables you wish to use, then read from xml and while reading just populate the List with the values you need

**EDIT:**

ex:
I suppose you know how to create a class, the method i use to read values from xml to a List is this:

```
List<YourClass> objectForValuesAndComments=new List<YourClass>();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\Location To XML\File.xml");
foreach (XmlNode subnode in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    YourClass objectToInsert=new YourClass();
    foreacht(XmlNode SubSubNode in subnode.ChildNodes)
    {
       if (SubSubNode.Name == "value")
       {
          objectToInsert.Value = SubSubNode.InnerText;
       }
       else if (SubSubNode.Name == "comment")
       {
          objectToInsert.Comment= SubSubNode.InnerText;
       }
    }
    objectForValuesAndComments.Add(objectToInsert);
 }
```

you can modify as you go on debug and see what suits you best :)
Hope it helps.

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do that as i am lost and new to this.

Comment: what are the values that are populated in the list of object?

Comment: Give me some more details to know how to help you with more accuracy

Comment: do you have any idea like after when you upload the file, it must show the language and version on a lable ?

Comment: Can you be more specific, what upload?

Comment: The user can browse resx file from many location. after loading the file the data inside the resx file get populated on the grid. Now i want the user to see the version and the language of the file on a lable (by default the version will always be English, the version starts on 100. how do i do this?

Comment: are those values stored in the xml file? or where do you store them?

Comment: can you please reply here on [enos.sitholimela@gmail.com]